# Issues with decode in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, decode

I need help with this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id
    CASE 
        WHEN a.sco = 0 
            THEN DECODE (a.x, 1, '1', 2, '2', 33, '3' null, '0', 0, '0', a.x) 
            ELSE DECODE (a.sco, 1, '1', 2, '2',33, '3' null, '0', 0, '0', a.sco)
    FORMAT a.dt, 'yyyy-MM') as date
    DECODE (a.sco, 1, '1', 2, '2',33, '3' null, '0', 0, '0', a.sco)
    DECODE (a.x, 1, '1', 2, '2',33, '3' null, '0', 0, '0', a.x)
FROM 
    aaa        a
```

I want to replace values from x depending on values of sco:

```
when sco = 0 values from x should be 1 if 1, if 2, 2 if 33, 3 if null, 0 if 0, 0
and when sco = 1,1, if 2, 2 if 33, 3 if null, 0 if 0, 0
and when x = 1,1, if 2, 2 if 33, 3 if null, 0 if 0, 0
```

| id | sco | x | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | 1 | 2019-04 |
| 002 | 0 | 2 | 2021-07 |
| 003 | 0 | 33 | 2009-09 |
| 004 | 0 | null | 2011-02 |
| 005 | 0 | 0 | 2020-02 |
| 001 | 1 | 1 | 2019-04 |
| 002 | 2 | 2 | 2021-07 |
| 003 | 33 | 33 | 2009-09 |
| 004 | null | null | 2011-02 |
| 005 | 2 | 0 | 2020-02 |

desired:

| id | sco | x | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | 1 | 2019-04 |
| 002 | 0 | 2 | 2021-07 |
| 003 | 0 | 3 | 2009-09 |
| 004 | 0 | 0 | 2011-02 |
| 005 | 0 | 0 | 2020-02 |
| 001 | 1 | 1 | 2019-04 |
| 002 | 2 | 2 | 2021-07 |
| 003 | 3 | 3 | 2009-09 |
| 004 | 0 | 0 | 2011-02 |
| 005 | 2 | 0 | 2020-02 |

Comment: Just use another CASE in place of DECODE

Comment: `DECODE()` is an Oracle function. You've tagged `sql-server` but are you sure you're using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @SteveFord didn't work